# Ubuntu 20.04.3 Gparted no me deja particionar

Tags: ubuntu

quería agradecerles de antemano su apoyo.

Acabo de instalar esta versión de Ubuntu en una máquina virtual. Cuando abro la aplicación veo que tengo una partición extendida con el 95% de disco usado, es en la que tengo instalado el SO. Yo quiero hacer una partición para datos y para SWAP, ¿alguien podría echarme un cable?

Como ven, la app me impide realizar una partición.
Agradecería una solución!
Gracias.
[image: La foto de la interfaz]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Primero tienes que hacer espacio, cambiando el tamaño de sda5, usando la opción Redimensionar/mover, cuando tengas espacio, crea una nueva partición para swap y otra para datos. Una vez arranques en sistema con el nuevo estado, tienes que tocar el /etc/fstab para que se vean los nuevos cambios, añadiendo la partición de swap y montando la de datos en un directorio cualquiera, por ejemplo /var/www o el que desees.

Comment: Guau estoy soroprendido, la verdad esque tengo el grado medio de SMR y estoy empezando ASIR, nunca había recibido instruncciones tan complicadas! (para mí! jajaj te agradezco de corazón tu respuesta, al final borré la máquina y particioné desde la instalación pero haré una práctica para resolver esa incidencia siguiendo tu método! Gracias de nuevo, con amor, Rubén.

Comment: Supongo que es ironía, pero en cualquier caso, mi comentario está a la altura de tu pregunta.

Comment: La verdad es que no lo era, tus instrucciones son muy profesionales en comparación a las que he ido recibiendo. Un saludo gracias de nuevo track3r.

Answer (score -2):

si estas trabajando con maquina virtual y aun no tienes nada te recomiendo reinstalar y desde alli eliges las particiones.

pero si no, pasate por este post y reintenta hacerlo desde comando a ver que tal te resulta

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: Gracias Salva, eso hice!